# what is ? operator in NotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, inotifypropertychanged

I have come across codes like

```
PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
```

I was trying to find what is the meaning of `PropertyChanged?` in the line of code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the syntax for **null propagation** which was [introduced in c# 6.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/october/csharp-the-new-and-improved-csharp-6-0). Here the `?` is the null-conditional operator. This code is equivalent to:

```
if(!(PropertyChanged is null))
    PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
```

Comment: It's more `var handler = PropertyChanged; if (handler != null) { handler.Invoke... }`. This is thread safe, your code is not.

Comment: @SimonMourier Your code is not more thread safe than mine.

Comment: @Soleil Wrong, in your code PropertyChanged may become null between the null check and the Invoke call.

Comment: @Soleil In a multi threaded application, an event handler can be cleared between the null check and the invoke, triggering an exception. Taking a copy prevents this.